# Using MS Unity error " The type does not have an accessible constructor. "

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Using MS Unity, I m getting "The type ICSService does not have an accessible constructor. " error at run time.

**Important Notes**

1. Interface ICSService and the class implementing it are in
       two separate assemblies
2. In my class implementation I am using `IUnitOfWork` another Interface which is coming from DAL which is
   again a seprate assambly.

Here is my contract:

```
namespace Demo.CustomTypes
{
    public interface ICSService
    {
        void AddClass(Class objClass);    
    }
}
```

Here is its implementation:

```
namespace Demo.Business
{
    public class CSService : ICSService
    {
        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

        public CSService ()
        {
            this.unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        }

        public CSService (IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
        }

          public void AddClass(Class objClass)
    {
        unitOfWork.ClassRepository.Insert(objClass);
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    }
}
```

Here is my Bootstrappe type registration code:

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {


        container.RegisterTypes(

           AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),

           WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,

           WithName.TypeName,

           WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);

    }
```

**EDIT**
If I modify my bootstraper code to below code it works fine but the question is why it is not working in automatica grestration of types. How I can make it work with automatic types ? I can't use below approach because this way I will have to manually do the stuff. Please help how to make it work with automatic configuration way mentioned above.

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

        container.RegisterType<ICSService, CSService>();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();    
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in `WithName.TypeName`. I suppose Unity makes a named registration, but it by default won't resolve named registrations.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to auto-register dependencies. Following links may help you to achieve same thing

- [CodePlex](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/)
- [Blog post](http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2012/05/adding-autoregistration-to-microsoft.html)
- [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityAutoRegistration/1.0.0.2)

I can understand the fact that your Interfaces are coming from various different areas but, i think as long as we stick to same naming conversion for class and interface (like name class Test and name of interface ITest) we can have correct dependency.